# How to deploy AdonisJS to IIS server?

Tags: javascript, api, adonis.js

The only thing I know to run adonisJS is by 'adonis serve' and it serve on port 3333 or any specific port. We need to deploy it on IIS server so I installed iisnode, etc. and the express server works on IIS. But when I add adonis project to IIS node its not working, I'm thinking how could I add this since I have to run 'adonis serve' to make it working. Or else I have to modified or tweak something to make it work?

Comment: Are you pointing to the right server.js?

it's located in web.config

Comment: Yes, I already solved, the problem was on the .env. The IP host should be the server and port set to 80.